# Amcharts5 set color palette in treemap

Tags: amcharts5

Hello Im using amcharts 5, right now im working in a treemap chart. The thing is, I want to set the color palette in order that the square shapes randomly get one of those colors.

Im setting the colors like this

```
series.get("colors").set("colors", [
                                  am5.color(0xdd6e42),
                                  am5.color(0xed7d31),
                                  am5.color(0xa5a5a5),
                                  am5.color(0xffc000),
                                  am5.color(0x425471),
                                  am5.color(0x9ba5b0),
                                  am5.color(0x71afe4),
                                  am5.color(0x44548c)  
                                ]);
```

But this is not working with exactly those colors.

The whole code is this:

```
var root = am5.Root.new("treemap");


                                root.setThemes([
                                  am5themes_Animated.new(root)
                                ]);
                                var container = root.container.children.push(
                                  am5.Container.new(root, {
                                    width: am5.percent(100),
                                    height: am5.percent(100),
                                    layout: root.verticalLayout
                                  })
                                );

                                var series = container.children.push(
                                  am5hierarchy.Treemap.new(root, {
                                    singleBranchOnly: false,
                                    downDepth: 1,
                                    upDepth: -1,
                                    initialDepth: 2,
                                    valueField: "valor",
                                    categoryField: "dato",
                                    childDataField: "children",
                                    nodePaddingOuter: 0,
                                    nodePaddingInner: 0,
                                    sort: "descending"
                                  })
                                );
                                series.get("colors").set("colors", [
                                  am5.color(0xdd6e42),
                                  am5.color(0xed7d31),
                                  am5.color(0xa5a5a5),
                                  am5.color(0xffc000),
                                  am5.color(0x425471),
                                  am5.color(0x9ba5b0),
                                  am5.color(0x71afe4),
                                  am5.color(0x44548c)  
                                ]);
                              

                                series.rectangles.template.setAll({
                                  strokeWidth: 2
                                });

                                var maxLevels = 2;
                                var maxNodes = 10;
                                var maxValue = 100;

                                var data = {
                                  dato: "Root",
                                  children: #{gastoDeFuncionamientoInversionBean.graficaTotalEjecutado}
                                };

                                series.data.setAll([data]);
                                series.set("selectedDataItem", series.dataItems[0]);

                                // Make stuff animate on load
                                series.appear(1000, 100);
```

The resulting charts colors differs from those selected colors